# Complexity of extending $P_4 $-partition of cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Surprising phenomena occurs when we want to extend a partial solution of some easy problems. We are given part of the solution and we want to decide whether we can extend it to a complete solution. Extendability problem transforms an easy problem to hard one.

For instance, Konig-Hall theorem states that all cubic bipartite graphs
are 3-edge colorable but the [extendability version becomes $NP$-complete](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.10088/full) if we are given the colors of some edges.

It is a fact that the edges of any bridgeless cubic graph can be partitioned into edge-disjoint paths $P_4$ (follows from [Petersen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem)). Given a set of paths $P_4$ (of three edges), I suspect that it is hard to decide the existence of edge partition into $P_4$ paths that include the given paths.

> Is this extendibility problem NP-complete?

**Extendibility problem**

INPUT: Bridgeless cubic graph $G(V,E)$ and set of paths $P_4=(e_i,e_j,e_k)$ where $e_i,e_j,e_k \in E$

OUTPUT: Is there a partition of the edge set $E$ into edge-disjoint paths $P_4$ that include the input paths